# How select next row pagination in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I'm sorry I'm weak for English.
i echo 2 row in each page . how echo next 2 row

```
SELECT *
FROM `mzmx_post`
JOIN mzmx_post_category 
WHERE mzmx_post.id = mzmx_post_category.post_id AND zmx_post_category.category_id = 5
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the two-arguments form of `LIMIT` to *offset* the result by a given number of rows, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mzmx_post`
JOIN mzmx_post_category ON mzmx_post.id = mzmx_post_category.post_id 
WHERE mzmx_post_category.category_id = 5
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2, 2      -- fetch records 3 and 4
```

This gives you the second page. If you want the third page, then:

```
LIMIT 4, 2
```

And so on.

Note that I modified your query so the joining condition between the tables is placed in the `ON` clause of the join rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use

```
LIMIT n,o
```

> where
>  n is the results per page
> o is the offset from the first result

for the p-th page the offset would be

> o = p * n
> where p = 0,1,2,....

Answer (score 0):

Better add one extra column (e.g. mzmx_post_key bigint) of Long type in each table and have sequential value on that column. Use that column to fetch data from DB from page wise.
sqL suery should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mzmx_post`
JOIN mzmx_post_category ON mzmx_post.id = mzmx_post_category.post_id 
WHERE mzmx_post_category.category_id = 5 and mzmx_post_key> ##last record key##
ORDER BY mzmx_post_key ASC
LIMIT 2
```